# Angular 2 header auth token missing

Tags: javascript, angular, express, header, jwt

I ran into an annoying error.
I send auth token in the http header, but when the express proccess the request then the auth token is missing.

here is my code:

**express authentication:**

```
app.all(process.env.API_BASE + "*", (req: any, res: any, next: any) => {

    if (req.path.includes(process.env.API_BASE + "login")) return next();
    if (req.path.includes(process.env.API_BASE + "signup")) return next();

    console.log(req.headers);

    return auth.authenticate((err: any, user: any, info: any) => {
        if (err) { return next(err); }
        if (!user) {
            if (info.name === "TokenExpiredError") {
                return res.status(401).json({ message: "Your token has expired. Please generate a new one" });
            } else {
                return res.status(401).json({ message: info.message });
            }
        }
        app.set("user", user);
        return next();
    })(req, res, next);
});
```

**angular2(v6) GET request:**

```
      public get<T>(path: string, param: string | number = '', queryParams: Object = {}, etag?: string): Promise<T> {
    const requestOptions = this.generateOptions();
    const builtUrl = this.buildUrl(path, param, queryParams);
    return this.http.get<T>(builtUrl, requestOptions)
    .toPromise()
    .catch(this.handleGlobalError);
  }

  private generateOptions() {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders()
    .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    .set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')

   if (this._token) {
    headers = Object.assign(headers, headers.set('Authorization', 
    this._token));
  }

  if (etag) {
   headers = Object.assign(headers, headers.set('If-None-Match', etag));
  }

  const options = {
   headers: headers,
  };

  return options;
 }
```

I also checked it in PostMan the headers looks like this:
[image]

The server logged the incoming requests, on the picture the first request came from POSTMAN, and the second came from my angular app:

[image]

**EDITED BASED ON NUNICORN ANSWER:**

```
private generateOptions(etag?: string) {
let withCred = false;
let headers = new HttpHeaders()
  .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
  .set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')

if (this._token) {
  withCred = true;
  headers.set('Authorization', this._token);
  //headers = Object.assign(headers, headers.set('Authorization', this._token));
}

const options = {
  headers: headers,
  withCredentials: withCred
};

return options;
}
```

unfortunately its still broken.

Comment: Can you look at the outgoing request in dev tools and see if the authorization header is being sent by Angular? Also, you have set `withCred` to `true` *only* in your `if(this._token)` block.... have you logged out `this._token` to make sure it actually has a value? If, for some reason, it doesn't have a value, that would explain why no header is being sent....

Answer (score 0):

Please replace the section

```
 if (this._token) {
         headers = Object.assign(headers, headers.set('Authorization', 
         this._token));
 }
```

with

```
 if (this._token) {
     headers.set('Authorization', this._token);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

When sending requests from `HttpClient`, you need to set the `withCredentials` override to `true`, otherwise your Authorization headers are stripped.

This normally more apparent with `POST` requests, but is also applicable to `GET` requests.

See: https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#get for more info on http overrides.